# Unused variable detection in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, variables, ssms

Is there a way to identify local variables that have been created (or even created and set to a value), but are never used again?  I'm thinking along the lines of when an IDE will underline such variables with a squiggly line.

If this isn't something that can be enabled within SSMS, are there any add-ins that do this?

(Particularly interested in SQL Server 2008 R2, if it matters)

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: "Find unused variables and parameters" is in the feature list of [SQL Prompt 5](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/feature-matrix)

Answer (score 2):

ApexSQL Refactor, a free SSMS and VS SQL formatting and refactoring add-in, has a feature that finds unused variables and parameters and cleans up your code by identifying and removing parameters and variables that aren’t used.

You can find more info about this feature in this [article](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/clean-up-sql-code-from-unused-variables/)

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*

Comment: I spent about 30 minutes checking out this feature and it appears to **not** be accurate is numerous cases.  It seems to always think user-defined types are unused.  Also, something as simple as: `Declare @today date;`
`Select @today = getdate();`  the plugin thinks that `@today` is unused.

Comment: @Ojen this issue is fixed in an upcoming release of ApexSQL Refactor. In your case it was showing "@today" variable as unused because it was only declared but not used in SELECT or WHERE clause. It would show the same for any data-type not just for UDT. Thanks, M

Comment: It doesn't look like this never got fixed (or got reintroduced). Every instance of "The variable has an assigned value, but none of the assigned values are ever used" is for a variable that is assigned and subsequently used in a conditional expression.

Answer (score 1):

SSMS doesn't do that, unfortunately. At all. Which surprises me in a way, because it can't be that hard to determine.

I don't know about add-ins, but Mr. Smith had a suggestion in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

you can try SqlCodeGuard from http://www.sqlcodeguard.com/  - free addin for SSMS

it has a bunch of t-sql code checks and have rule "MI005 Variable is declared but never used"

Comment: Trend Micro told me the website is questionable, but the software worked (after I ran a virus check)

Comment: The link for SQL Code Guard redirects to SQL Prompt. Elsewhere, I found the explanation for this: *"SQL Code Guard SSMS add-in for SSMS 2016 has been deprecated as its functionality has been ported to SQL Prompt."*