# How to find unused variables in a sql script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that has quite a lot of declared variables. However, I noticed some of them haven't been used. How can I clean up the code in such a way I know which ones have been used and which ones have not been set anywhere in the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to find unused variable in a stored procedure using SSMS, you need to use third party tools.

Please refer

http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/clean-up-sql-code-from-unused-variables/
[Unused variable detection in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624319/unused-variable-detection-in-sql-server)